# Using Unity in a three layer application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have an application composed from DAL, BLL and the API layer and Iam using unity for injection. In the Business layer i have a class called AuthRepository where it inherit from IAuthRepository following is a part of this class.

class AuthRepository in BLL:

```
public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository, IDisposable
{
    private UserAuthContext _authContext;
    private UserManager<UserInfo> _userManager;

    // Issue 1: this constructor should be delete and use injection instead 
    // to solve the problem in class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider
    public AuthRepository()
    {
        _authContext = new UserAuthContext();
        _userManager = new UserManager<UserInfo>(new UserStore<UserInfo>(_authContext));
    }

    public AuthRepository(UserAuthContext authContext)
    {
        _authContext = authContext;
        //this._authContext = new UserAuthContext();
        _userManager = new UserManager<UserInfo>(new UserStore<UserInfo>(_authContext)); // TODO: implement usermanager with Unity
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserEntity createUserModel)
    {
        UserInfo user = new UserInfo
        {
            FirstName = createUserModel.FirstName,
            LastName = createUserModel.LastName,
            UserName = createUserModel.UserName,
            Email = createUserModel.Email
        };
        var result =  await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, createUserModel.Password);
        return result;
    }
```

In The API Layer i have another class which is called SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider, the class take care of the Bear token provided by Owin following is the class

Class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider in API Layer:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the first constructor in AuthRepository should be removed to make application lousely coupled. If i delete this constructor, so i need to send a parameter of type UserAuthContext from the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class in the method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials at this statement

> using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())

and thats what i dont want to do, the API Layer should communicate with the BLL  and not the DAL.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `Unity` but in general an IoC-container should take care of injecting the dependencies via constructor injection. In your case you should change the `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` and the `AuthRepository` classes.

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider 
{
    private IAuthRepository _authRepository;

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IAuthRepository authRepository)
    {
        _authRepository = authRepository
    }

    ...

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        // no need for new repository anymore
        // class already has repository injected 

        IdentityUser user = await _authRepository.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}

public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository, IDisposable
{
    public AuthRepository(UserAuthContext userAuthContext, UserManager<UserInfo> userManager)
    {
        _userAuthContext = userAuthContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    ...
}
```

If your `AuthRepository` class does not need the `UserAuthContext` (your code snippet only uses it to create a `UserManager<UserInfo>`) then you might remove that class from the constructor and move that dependency to the constructor of the `UserManager<T>` class:

```
public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository, IDisposable
{
    public AuthRepository(UserManager<UserInfo> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    ...
}

public class UserManager<T>
{
    private UserAuthContext _userAuthContext;

    public UserManager<T>(UserAuthContext userAuthContext)
    {
        _userAuthContext = userAuthContext;
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally you need to register all classes that must be injected with Unity as described [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660923(v=pandp.20).aspx)

One more thing: You'd better replace the concrete classes in the constructors with interfaces when possible. In general it is better to program against interfaces than to concrete classes. A nice overview can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702246/Program-to-Interface-not-Implementation-Beginners)

**Edit**

Added body of `GrantResourceOnwerCredentials` to stress that you no longer need a new repository because the object has already access to the injected one.

**Update**

In your start up class you should not create a new `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` but ask a [abstract factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) that has a dependency on `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider` to do it for you.

Comment: thats actually what i tried to do, but when i register SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider in the Startup class, i will face the same problem, that the constructor in of SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider needs parameter of typ IAuthRepository.. do u think that DI with propreties instead of constructor could solve this problem ?

Comment: You should register a concrete class for `IAuthRepository` using `RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>()` like this: `yourContainer.RegisterType<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();`

Comment: i did bro, i already done this step. my problem is that i have to send a parameter of type UserAuthContext in SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method,

Comment: I tried the first solution u provided but, the problem is that i configure the token in the startup class as following `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };
        }` so here i need also to send a parameter in SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider when i do as u mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Follow as instructed by venerik, so add a constructor that takes interface of IAuthRepository:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider 
{
    private IAuthRepository _authRepository;

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IAuthRepository authRepository)
    {
        _authRepository = authRepository
    }

    ...
```

Then, as you mentioned when you 'register SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider in the Startup class' you need to pass a parameter of type '*IAuthRepository*', which you can do by adding the following:

```
var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider((IAuthRepository)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IAuthRepository)))
        };
```

In the code above the *provider* line is where you need to inject your concrete class.

p.s. I am presuming you are registering your Unity config in your Owin startup file i.e.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        ...
```

Comment: I will be able to give a more detailed example next week, too much on at the moment, sorry.